# ¿Como puedo hacer que al presionar un boton, se ejecute la función a la que este mismo llama pero después de un tiempo?

Tags: javascript

Pues bien, estoy haciendo un piedra, papel o tijeras en javascript y tengo 3 botones (piedra, papel y tijera). Quiero que al ejecutar alguno de esos tres botones la función espere un tiempo para ejecutarse y que aparezca un simbolo que ande girando al cargar, lo intenté hacer de muchas formas pero fueron inutiles.
A continuación les muestro mi código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Piedra papel o tijera</title>
    <script src="Piedra, papel o tijeras.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Ceeseese.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/60b90458fd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Texto">
      <p><strong>Elige tu opcion</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="Btns">
    <a href="#" class="Botones" onclick="Opcion(0)"><i class="fas fa-hand-scissors"></i>Tijera</a>
    <a href="#" class="Botones" onclick="Opcion(1);"><i class="fas fa-hand-rock"></i>Piedra</a>
    <a href="#" class="Botones" onclick="Opcion(2);"><i class="fas fa-hand-paper"></i>Papel</a>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y ahora mi javascript:

```
function Opcion(miOpcion) {
  var nombre = ["Tijera","Piedra","Papel"]
  var cpu = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))
if(miOpcion === 0 && cpu === 2 || miOpcion === 1 && cpu === 0 || miOpcion === 2 && cpu === 1)
{
  alert("Jugador: " + nombre[miOpcion]);
  alert("Contrincante: " + nombre[cpu]);
  alert("Ganaste, sos un capo")
}
else if(miOpcion === 0 && cpu === 1 || miOpcion === 1 && cpu === 2 || miOpcion === 2 && cpu === 0)
{
  alert("Jugador: " + nombre[miOpcion]);
  alert("Contrincante: " + nombre[cpu]);
  alert("Perdiste, sos un pete")
}
else {
  alert("Jugador: " + nombre[miOpcion]);
  alert("Contrincante: " + nombre[cpu]);
  alert("Empataste")
}
}
```

Comment: Creo que vas a tener que jugar con un timeout. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas usar [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), donde el primer parámetro es la función a ejecutar y, el segundo, el tiempo que debe pasar para que se ejecute.

Dentro de tu función `Opcion(miOpcion)`, el primer paso es mostrar la imagen, después crear in intervalo (en este caso, de 1 segundo), donde realizas las operaciones necesarias y, posteriormente, ocultas la imagen y muestras el mensaje deseado.

Para mostrar y ocultar la imagen se usa el método `.toggle()` de [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) que solo agrega al elemento la clase especificada si no existe, o la elimina si ya la tiene.

Apliqué algunas mejoras a tu código, como evitar repeticiones al crear una variable con el mensaje que se debe mostrar y una sola alerta con varias líneas, aprovechando las ventajas de las [plantillas de cadena de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

```js
let imgLoad;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    imgLoad = document.querySelector('#loading');
}
function Opcion(miOpcion) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Ocultar imagen
    imgLoad.classList.toggle('active');
    
    var nombre = ["Tijera","Piedra","Papel"];
    var cpu = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
    var msg = '';
    if(miOpcion === 0 && cpu === 2 || miOpcion === 1 && cpu === 0 || miOpcion === 2 && cpu === 1) {
      msg = 'Ganaste, sos un capo';
    } else if(miOpcion === 0 && cpu === 1 || miOpcion === 1 && cpu === 2 || miOpcion === 2 && cpu === 0) {
      msg = 'Perdiste, sos un pete';
    } else {
      msg = 'Empataste';
    }
  // Mostrar imagen
  imgLoad.classList.toggle('active');
    alert(`      Jugador: ${nombre[miOpcion]}
      Contrincante: ${nombre[cpu]}
      ${msg}`);
  }, 1000); // <--- Ajusta el tiempo a tu gusto por milisegundos
}
```

```css
#loading {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
#loading.active { display:block; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Piedra papel o tijera</title>
    <script src="Piedra, papel o tijeras.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Ceeseese.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/60b90458fd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Texto">
      <p><strong>Elige tu opcion</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="Btns">
    <a href="#" class="Botones" onclick="Opcion(0)"><i class="fas fa-hand-scissors"></i>Tijera</a>
    <a href="#" class="Botones" onclick="Opcion(1);"><i class="fas fa-hand-rock"></i>Piedra</a>
    <a href="#" class="Botones" onclick="Opcion(2);"><i class="fas fa-hand-paper"></i>Papel</a>
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6viz.gif" id="loading">
  </body>
</html>
```

**Nota:** Ajusta el tiempo deseado y cambia la imagen por una de tu preferencia, esta la encontré en una pregunta de SO en inglés.

Comment: Escribí el código tal y como está y me aparece en la consola: Uncaught TypeError: imgLoad is null --- Piedra, papel o tijeras.js:4:3 (la parte del código donde está el error)

Comment: Recuerda incluir el código Javascript antes de la etiqueta `</body>`, ya sea directamente o guardarlo en un archivo externo. Si lo pones arriba, la imagen todavía no ha sido agregada al DOM y por eso obtienes el error.

Comment: Nop, no funciona, me sigue tirando el mismo error, te mandaría el código pero aca solanente se permiten como 600 caracteres... Si me puedes seguir ayudando mejor, pero si no, muchas gracias por aportar! PD: al final al if lo dejé como estaba antes, no se si tendrá algo que ver...

Comment: ¿Agregaste la imagen al código, con `id="loading"`? Modifiqué la respuesta para cargar la variable de la imagen hasta que se haya cargado el DOM.

Comment: mmm... Si te refieres a poner   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6viz.gif" id="loading">, sip ya está puesto en el html como me lo mandaste, te mandaría mi código si quieres pero no se si hay manera de mandartelo por mensaje privado o si quieres puedo volver a hacer una pregunta...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) para simular tu pausa; esta función recibe como parámetros una función a ejecutar, un tiempo de espera (en **milisegundos**) y los argumentos para la función a ejecutar(opcional, en caso de requerirse).

e.g.

```js
document.getElementById('trigger')
        .addEventListener('click', () => {
        
          // Cuando se disparé el click, mostrará el cargando.
          document.getElementById('lbl').innerText = "Cargando..."
          
          // Pasado tres segundos lo ocultará
          setTimeout(/* aquí va la función */
            function (){
              // Esto se ejecutará transcurrido el tiempo indicado
              document.getElementById('lbl').innerText = ""
            },
            3000 // Tiempo de espera en milisegundos
            )
        })
```

```html
<button id="trigger">Click me!</button>
<label id="lbl"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar un setTimeOut o puedes utilizar promesas. No se realmente si quieres que se muestre un spinner hasta que llegue la decision de la CPU o quieres que se muestre en cada paso... tendras que hacer uso document.apendChild y modificar clases del css y html.

```js
function Opcion(miOpcion) {
    var nombre = ["Tijera", "Piedra", "Papel"]
    var cpu = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))
    if (miOpcion === 0 && cpu === 2 || miOpcion === 1 && cpu === 0 || miOpcion === 2 && cpu === 1) {
        alert("Jugador: " + nombre[miOpcion]);
        setTimeout(() => {
            alert("Contrincante: " + nombre[cpu]);
            alert("Ganaste, sos un capo")
        }, 3500);



    }
    else if (miOpcion === 0 && cpu === 1 || miOpcion === 1 && cpu === 2 || miOpcion === 2 && cpu === 0) {
        alert("Jugador: " + nombre[miOpcion]);
        setTimeout(() => {
            alert("Contrincante: " + nombre[cpu]);
            alert("Perdiste, sos un pete")
        }, 3500);

    }
    else {
        alert("Jugador: " + nombre[miOpcion]);
        setTimeout(() => {
            alert("Contrincante: " + nombre[cpu]);
            alert("Empataste")
        }, 3500);

    }


}
```